# Spring Boot properties not loading 2.1.5

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I have written a spring boot app to monitor jobs and have wired the configuration properties for the clients to call services in the job services. I am using a yml file called application-test.yml in src/test/resources. I have also set the active profiles when running the test to -Dspring.profiles.active='test' and spring says the active profile is test. However when I run the tests, the configuration properties host and path are always null. Here is my configuration file:

```
spring:
 profiles: test
```

myservices:
  clients:

```
printservice:
  host: app/sms/appdev.com
  path: jobs/{jobId}

monitorNgService:
  host: app/monitor/appdev.com
  path: iqueue/jobs/{jobKey}/servers
```

Here are my classes for the configurations:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myservices.clients")
 class  PrintServiceProperties{
 String host;
 String path;
 }
```

The other configuration class loads the second configuration in the yml file. It also has null for host and path. Here is that file;

```
   @Configuration
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myservices.clients")
   class  MonitorNgServiceProperties{
      String host;
      String path;
   }
```

I am injecting this class in a class that uses these properties but they are null

Here is the class

```
@Service


 @Import(MonitorNgServiceProperties)
   @Slf4j
   class MonitorService implements InitializingBean{
    @Autowired
    MonitorNgServiceProperties monitorNgService
```

I have spent hours on this but can't figure out why the properties won't load. I'd be really grateful for help in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing the last prefix:

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myservices.clients.printservice")
```

Comment: Thank you, looks much better.